# How is saveenv implemented inside u-boot?

Tags: environment-variables, u-boot

I am trying to figure out which part of code inside the u-boot is responsible for writing to the device from the RAM, when we do a `saveenv` after `setenv`. I could find `printenv` and `setenv`, but not `saveenv`. Can someone please shed some light on it?

Answer (score 3):

That depends on what nonvolatile storage the platform is configured for. In any case common/nv_edit.c will be built. But (for example) if env lives in SPI flash, then saveenv() in common/env_sf.c will get built and linked. Do "grep saveenv common/*.c" and you'll see other storage options (eeprom, flash, mmc, nand etc).

CONFIG_ options for any platform are in the appropriate .h under include/configs/. Compare ENV-related options with storage options, that should lead to the right part of code for your platform.